# How to display header on any given page after setting the stack to 'headerMode: "none" '?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a stack navigator in a react-native project, using the react-navigation library. Initially I dont want any header displayed. On forthcoming screens, I want a dynamic header displayed. so in my navigator config object looks like:

`const authStackConfig = { initialRouteName: 'Login', headermode: 'none' };`

and on the screen implementation I have

`static navigationOptions = {headerMode:'screen'}`

but headerMode isn't a navigationOption property...

I've tried changing the navigator config option from`headerMode` to `header: null`, and then on each screen setting the `title` of the header with `static navigationOptions = {title: "Some title"}` but that doesn't work either. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to explicitly set the stack config object with  `headerMode:'screen'`, which allows for screen-to-screen customization. then on the screens you want a header, define navigationOptions in the stack's route config object with a `title` to show in header and then in the given screen define navigationOptions like `static navigationOptions = { headerShown: true/false}`